# Basic Counter for login c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm stuck with a login counter to keep track on how many times someone has tried to login. (Failed attempts)

Im at VisionPro Designer from Cognex which uses C# and .NET.
When the maximum attempts is reached within the timeframe starting from the first failed attempt (let's say 5 minutes) the password box will be blocked.

I'm a beginner at programming, just self taught.

The current settings is just none, got a user database built-in the program.

A textbox for username and a passwordbox for the password (Obviously).
I set it up so when the passwordbox got a changed value it matches the credentials with the user database and if that's "true" you get to the advanced options page. And i dont want any non-trusted machine operators reaching the advanced settings page.

The program uses "Value Tags" that you can get the value or change the value wherever you are in the program, got a tag set up for the loginattempts "Tag_LoginCount"

Here's the passwordbox code:

```
if ($System.Users.Login($Tag_InputUsername, $Tag_InputPassword))  
{
    $Pages.MainPage.PasswordBox.Password = ""; //Resets the passwordbox password at login

    $HMI.ShowPage("LidSettings"); //Opens the Lidsettings page

    $Pages.LidSettings.Slider2.Value = 0; //Disables the advanced settings option
}
else
{  
    $Pages.MainPage.PasswordBox.Password = ""; //resets password
}
```

Comment: You should be storing the failed attempts in your database. Each time the credentials are evaluated as false you should update a column with the count.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already got a tag called "Tag_LoginCount" defined.  I presume it's an Integer.  You can check existing tags and add new ones in the 'Tag Manager'.

I'd consider adding a few more tags:

- FailedLogins (Integer)
- TimeOfFirstLogin (DateTime)
- UserLockedOut (Boolean)
- UserLockoutStart (DateTime)

To use tags in the script, simply prefix the tag names with a dollar sign (e.g., $FailedLogins), or drag-and-drop them from the Toolbox to your script.

The script below should achieve something close to what you want:

```
const int USER_LOCKOUT_PERIOD = 10;
const int MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 8;
const int LOGIN_TIMEFRAME = 5;

// Check if user is locked out
int minutesUserLockedOut = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract($UserLockoutStart).TotalMinutes;

if ($UserLockedOut && (minutesUserLockedOut > USER_LOCKOUT_PERIOD))
{
    $UserLockedOut = false;
}

if ($UserLockedOut)
{
    int userLockoutMinutesRemaining = (int)(USER_LOCKOUT_PERIOD - minutesUserLockedOut);
    $HMI.ShowMessage("Too many failed login attempts.  System locked for " + userLockoutMinutesRemaining + " minutes.");
    $Pages.MainPage.PasswordBox.Password = ""; //resets password
    return;
}

// Reset number of failed logins if first failed login more than LOGIN_TIMEFRAME minutes ago
TimeSpan minutesSinceFirstBadLogin = (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract($TimeOfFirstBadLogin).TotalMinutes;
if (minutesSinceFirstBadLogin > LOGIN_TIMEFRAME)
{
    $FailedLogins = 0;
}

if ($System.Users.Login($Tag_InputUsername, $Tag_InputPassword))
{
    // Successful login!  Reset number of bad logins
    $FailedLogins = 0;

    $HMI.ShowPage("LidSettings"); //Opens the Lidsettings page
    $Pages.LidSettings.Slider2.Value = 0; //Disables the advanced settings option
}
else
{
    // If this is the first failed login, record the time
    if ($FailedLogins == 0)
    {
        $TimeOfFirstBadLogin = DateTime.Now;
    }

    // Increment the number of failed logins
    $FailedLogins = $FailedLogins + 1;

    // Lock the user out if the number of failed logins exceeds maximum allowed
    if ($FailedLogins > MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS)
    {
        $UserLockedOut = true;
        $UserLockoutStart = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

$Pages.MainPage.PasswordBox.Password = ""; //resets password
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to say what you might need here, given your description. I'll assume that the code snippet you presented is inside an event handler processing some user input. I'll put the event handler inside a class. To be able to preserve the value of a counter between multiple invocations of the handler, you need to store the value of the counter somewhere outside of the handler. One approach is to have a class level variable.

```
public class C
{
    public C()
    {
        _counter = 0; // initialize the counter when creating a class instance
    {

    private int _counter;

    private void Handler()
    {
        if (System.Users.Login(Tag_InputUsername, Tag_InputPassword))  
        {
            Pages.MainPage.PasswordBox.Password = ""; //Resets the passwordbox password at login

            HMI.ShowPage("LidSettings"); //Opens the Lidsettings page

            Pages.LidSettings.Slider2.Value = 0; //Disables the advanced settings option

            _counter++; // increment the counter field
        }
        else
        {  
            Pages.MainPage.PasswordBox.Password = ""; //resets password
        }
    }
}
```

I presume that's not exactly what you want, because there is no distinction between a valid and invalid login attempt, but you should be able to figure out how to adapt the example.

Comment: What's with those php like variables? O.o

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Thanks, I didn't notice it. Not sure what they are doing in the original post.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman The program im using is a coalition of several programming languages plus it's own, "Tag Manager"

Comment: I'm building a program which is visually quality checking the parts we produce with 3 cameras per line. im done with the program so im setting up the UI which the operators can change some selected settings on a touchscreen on the machine. and to do that i need some basic programming.

Comment: @Kapol i just need a way to change the value of "Tag_LoginCount". The "Tag" itself holds the value as long as you like, until you reset it with a command. no need for components, classes and such.

Comment: @Kapol That's because i haven't figured out a way to change the value of it yet. Figured you guys could help me with that.

Example: "$Tag_LoginCount = +1" before the page change takes place.
and 
i can link the value of the tag with the PasswordBoxes visible value so it becomes inactive when the value of the tag has reached 5.

and a foreman has to put in his credentials to unlock it, 
i have given all the foremen login credits.

thats the plan atleast.

Comment: @bokolle Can't you just substitute the `_counter` variable from my example with `Tag_LoginCount`? I'm confused.

Comment: @Kapol The problem is that I just don't know how to use it properly, I can set the camera at my anus, take a picture and build a program to get the result of what i ate 2 weeks ago. But when it comes to Scripting I'm so damn lost. I basically know if and return variables.
don't really know anything about namespaces, counters and the rest.
I know exacly how the basics of programming works, but i can't create it myself.

Comment: it Says: "Invalid character '$'."

Comment: @bokolle That's because you cannot use `$` in a variable name in C#. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Looks like you need a good C# book. Don't mix programming languages ;)
Try "Head first C#" and thank me later.